# Increasing the size of a WPF application

Tags: wpf, xaml, resize, scale

I've just created my first WPF application (3 calculators inside 3 different tabs).

The entire application has been built using widths/margins/paddings as static values, since I originally didn't know that dynamic values can be used by just putting an asterix after the value.

The client has come back to me though and has asked me to increase the size of the app, that includes form fields, tabs, font-sizes, grids etc...

What would be the easiest (and/or quickest) way to do this? I'd hate to go value by value resizing every single element since there are quite a few.

I can provide code but there is **lots** of it and I'm not sure of how much help it would be.

Appreciate your help,

Marko

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put it all in one ViewBox, play with viewbox size to change the app size

Comment: Do that or look into LayoutTransform/ScaleTransform

Comment: Cheers let me have a crack at it.

Answer (score -3):

Write an XSLT transform to take your XAML as input and spit out appropriate modified XAML, which you put back in your app.

Comment: Thanks @Dathan - what exactly am I transforming though, can you show a sample perhaps?

Comment: @Marko can you provide a snippet of your original XAML with the hard-coded sizes (as an update to the question, maybe)?  I can update my answer with a sample transform based on that.